# Display all properties and if property is a class display its properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using reflection to loop through classes of a DLL and display the properties of that class; but there are cases where the property is another class, and I need to loop through that property's properties and display them.

What I currently have will only display the properties, and not sub properties:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Path\Domain.dll");

            int count = 0;
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass))
            {               
                var node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(type.FullName);

                var x = ((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)((assembly.GetTypes()))[count]).DeclaredProperties;

                x.ToList().ForEach(item => treeView1.Nodes[count].Nodes.Add(item.Name));

                count++;                
            }           
        }
```

Any help to display sub properties

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is recursively do an iteration. Create a member that displays the properties, and call the member itself with the sub properties. This might give you an idea:

```
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
            ListProperties(myObject.GetType(), 2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void ListProperties(Type type, int ident)
        {
            var x = type.GetProperties();
            Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', ident) + "Class: " + type.FullName);
            int newIdent = ident += 2;
            x.ToList().Where(item => item.PropertyType.IsClass).ToList().ForEach(item => ListProperties(item.PropertyType, newIdent));

        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public SubClass PropertySubClass1 { get; set; }

        public SubClass PropertySubClass2 { get; set; }

    }

    class SubClass
    {
        public SubSubClass PropertySubSubClass { get; set; }
    }

    class SubSubClass
    {

    }
}
```

In this code fragment in the Main you see that a member ListProperties is called. In this member, the property type is listed, and then it calls itself (in the last line for the sub properties).
Instead of 'ident' for pretty-printing in this example, you have to add the node text in a similar way. 
The output of this example is:

[image]

Comment: getting stack overflow exceptions